# CSRF verification failed for Django-admin

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin

I recently installed `Django==4.0.4` and tried to login to Django-admin panel, It is working fine in local.
But got this CSRF exception in production

```
Request aborted(403)

CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
```

any ideas ?

Comment: Can you tell us more about your production environment? Do you have a client application, e.g. in React / Angular / Vue / etc.?

Comment: I'm not using any client application right now.

Comment: "But got this CSRF exception in production"—when you do what? Are you trying to submit a form? Are you [including the `{% csrf_token %}` in your form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/csrf/)?

Comment: I was trying to login with admin credentials in django admin, and got this issue,
for django admin, i guess we don't need a {% csrf_token %}

Comment: Of course you do. Why wouldn't you need a CSRF token to log in? Anyway, if you're using the default admin templates [this should already be included](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d5bc36203057627f6f7d0c6dc97b31adde6f4313/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/login.html#L46). How are you setting your [`SECRET_KEY`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#std-setting-SECRET_KEY).

Comment: It was working fine it local server, but when i deployed the application in production server, It raised an issue like this